# What apparatus is needed to get a balloon full of anhydrous carbon dioxide from solid carbon dioxide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbon-dioxide

I'm currently planning a research project (new to this) and we need to bubble CO2 through our reaction mixture, however we are not able to use compressed gas so have been advised to pass CO2 from dry ice over a drying agent and syphon it into a balloon. Is there any literature on this procedure, any help much appreciated.

Comment: That`s not *research*, thats a lab course task. ;) How about you propose some setup, and we tell you if it would work?

Comment: Hint: Look up lab procedures of Grignard reactions with carbon dixoxyde *in* the reaction flask.